# How to send the logs from kubernetes pod to host pc

Tags: kubernetes, logging

I use k9s to access the bash from the pod where I keep the logs of my project.

Reading the logs with a cat is annoying, so I want to send them to my pc.

[image: img]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [kubectl cp](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#cp) command.

`kubectl cp default/<some-pod>:/logs/app.log app.log`